# Reuse Same Function inside a Function

Tags: php

I've been thinking of the best way to create a dynamically nested

  navigation using PHP, and that is to use a function that gets called within the same function to generate the different navigation levels.

I have a database that consists of 3 fields:

page - Used as a unique identifier for the navigation item

title - Used to store the title of the navigation item.

owner - used to store what page this page is associated to. (Parent page)

I'm trying to make the followed menu dynamic

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1 of Sub Menu 4</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 of Sub Menu 4</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3 of Sub Menu 4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm having issues, as the page crashes upon calling the function again inside the same function, as it creates a continuous loop. How do I prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I've now added my PHP code so far to my original post! ;)

Answer (score 0):

A function can simply call itself, by name.

For example: (this is an actual method from one of my classes)

```
protected function getParentName( $pid ) {

        foreach( $this->input as $a ) {
            if( $pid == $a['id'] ) {
                $this->bc = '<a href="/category/' . $a['id'] . '">' . $a['name'] . '</a> >> ' . $this->bc;
                if( !empty( $a['i_parent'] ) ) {
                    $this->getParentName( $a['i_parent'] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get the following error: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\Xampp\htdocs\menu.php on line 4

Comment: @user826855 that's because this function must be inside a class.

Comment: Can a function only call itself if it's in a class?

Comment: No, a regular function can also call itself. Just remove the 'protected' and $this and basically use the same idea - call the function from inside that function, passing it some new params

Comment: I've think I've cracked it now, but how do I get something to display only on the first function call?

Comment: What you can do is to pass a second param to your function, initially make it null, then each recursive call will pass it's own return value. You then concatinate (append or prepend, whatever you need) that extra passed param to the return value of the function. At the end you just use the return value of your function. That's what you want to show eventually